# Kivy - formatting issues with a scrollview pane.

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to create the following in Kivy: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2R6U.jpg. Each new recipe in that screenshot is something I want to be able to add to the screen as a block. So far I have the following code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.checkbox import CheckBox 

from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

class ShoppingScreen(Screen):

    def addRecipe(self):
        self.ids.grid.add_widget(RecipeLabel(recipeName = "test"))
        self.ids.grid.add_widget(Recipe())
        self.ids.grid.add_widget(Ingredient(ingredientName = "test", quantity="test"))

    def activate_checkbox(self):
        print("test")

class RecipeLabel(BoxLayout):
    recipeName = StringProperty('')

class Recipe(BoxLayout):
    ingredient = StringProperty('Ingredient')
    quantity = StringProperty('Quantity')

class theScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class Ingredient(BoxLayout):
    ingredientName = StringProperty('')
    quantity = StringProperty('')

root_widget = Builder.load_string('''
#:import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory

theScreenManager:
    ShoppingScreen:

<ShoppingScreen>:
    name: 'shopping'
    dropdown: dropdown.__self__
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            size_hint: 1, .3
            Button:
                text: '<'
                size_hint: .1, 1
                font_size: 75
                background_normal: ""
                background_color: 0.18, .5, .92, 1
                on_release: app.root.current = 'main' 

            Label:
                text: 'Shopping List'
                halign: 'left'
                font_size: 50
                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgb: 0.18, .5, .92
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size
            Widget:
                size_hint: .1, 1
                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgb: 0.18, .5, .92
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            size_hint: 1, .4
            spacing: 50
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgb: 0.8, 0.8, 0.8
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            Label:
                text: 'Duration'
                font_size: 30
                color: 0.18, .5, .92, 1

            Button:
                id: btn
                text: 'Select a duration of time...'
                font_size: 15
                on_release: dropdown.open(self)
                height: '48dp'
                pos_hint: { 'top' : 0.75}
                size_hint: .8, .5

            DropDown:
                id: dropdown
                on_parent: self.dismiss()
                on_select: btn.text = '{}'.format(args[1])

                Button:
                    text: '1 week'
                    font_size: 15
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: '48dp'
                    on_release: root.addRecipe()

                Button:
                    text: '2 weeks'
                    font_size: 15
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: '48dp'
                    #on_release: root.formatScreen(5, 'Vegetarian Lasagne')

                Button:
                    text: '3 weeks'
                    font_size: 15
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: '48dp'
                    #on_release: root.formatScreen(3, 'Tomato and linguine')
            Widget:
                size_hint: .02, 1

        BoxLayout:
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgb: 1, 1, 1
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            ScrollView:
                scroll_timeout: 250
                scroll_distance: 20
                do_scroll_y: True
                do_scroll_x: False

                GridLayout:
                    id: grid
                    height: self.minimum_height
                    cols: 1
                    spacing: 45
                    padding: 25
                    size_hint_y: None

<RecipeLabel>:
    Label:
        text: root.recipeName
        color: (0.18, .5, .92, 1)
        font_size: 30
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgb: 0.18, .5, .92
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos 
                size: self.size 
<Ingredient>:
    Label:
        text: root.ingredientName
        color: (0.18, .5, .92, 1)
        font_size: 15
    Label:
        text: root.quantity
        color: (0.18, .5, .92, 1)
        font_size: 15
    CheckBox:
        active: True
        on_active: root.activate_checkbox
        color: (0.18, .5, .92, 1)

<Recipe>:
    Label:
        text: 'Ingredient'
        color: (0.18, .5, .92, 1)
        font_size: 20
    Label:
        text: 'Quantity'  
        color: (0.18, .5, .92, 1)
        font_size: 20
    Widget:
        size_hint: .2, 1

''')

class temprecipeapp(App):
    def build(self):
        return root_widget

if __name__ == "__main__":
    temprecipeapp().run()
```

If you run this code (just copy and paste it into a Python file and it should work if you have Kivy installed), select '1 week' from the dropdown menu to load one of these 'recipe blocks' I'm trying to create, two things go wrong. Firstly, the checkbox is not clickable at all. I cannot change its state. Secondly, the label of the 'test' label at the top of the scrollview should have a blue background however it doesn't show up at all. I believe both these issues are something to do with the scrollview/grid however I can't be sure. Any ideas what I should do?